# Event TableFixHeader

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I download a custom table from [this site](https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders).
I want to show the value of the cell I click.

```
TableFixHeaders table = (TableFixHeaders) findViewById(R.id.table_1);
table.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));   
table.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){
        @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        TextView Cl = (TextView) table.getChildAt(1);
        Toast.makeText(this, Cl.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
        }
});
```

The problem is I can't intercept any event in my main activity.

Answer (score 0):

I also have downloaded this very nice widget with scrolling columns and rows. And I also needed to get a response on a click at a certain cell. It didn't come, but I found the reason here:
In `TableFixHeaders.java`, module `OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` add this line at the beginning:

```
super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

This call will make sure that other touch methods gets called! So it should also work for longclicks as well!
I have added my click-handler to the specific view (cell) in module `GetView(int row, int column, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` when convertView is inflated first time. Then I an able to have different handlers to different cells (columns-headers, data-cells etc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed code:

```
      private View getBody(final int row,final int column, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_table, parent, false);
            }
        /*if(row == 8){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.row8); //if row8 need different colour
        }*/else {
                //Change table color using bg_table_col
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(row % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.bg_table_color1 : R.drawable.bg_table_color2);
            }
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(records.get(row).getItem(column + 1));
            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    detailsearchPaperID = records.get(row).getItem(0);
                    final String S;
                    S = detailsearchPaperID + " : " + records.get(row).getItem(column + 1);
                    Log.d(TAG, S);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), S, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //...
                    // we will not start intent here but after performing search
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

If you add the listener as explained in previous post (when convertView is inflated first time), this will work only on the first view, before performing any scroll.

My code works even if you have performed scroll. Of course you need to add

```
    super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

as explained earlier

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this [wrapper for InqBarna's library](https://github.com/miguelbcr/TableFixHeaders-Wrapper).

This is a code snippet of how to achieve the click events on table body. 
You can see more ellaborated [examples here](https://github.com/miguelbcr/TableFixHeaders-Wrapper/tree/master/samples-wrapper/src/main/java/com/miguelbcr/tablefixheaderssamples).

```
    TableFixHeaderAdapter.ClickListener<List<String>, BasicCellViewGroup> clickListenerBody = new TableFixHeaderAdapter.ClickListener<List<String>, BasicCellViewGroup>() {
        @Override
        public void onClickItem(List<String> array, BasicCellViewGroup viewGroup, int row, int column) {
            viewGroup.vg_root.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorYellow));
            Snackbar.make(viewGroup, "Click on " + viewGroup.textView.getText() + " (" + row + "," + column + ")", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

and so on for the rest of the table cells:

```
    adapter.setClickListenerFirstHeader(clickListenerHeader);
    adapter.setLongClickListenerFirstHeader(longClickListenerHeader);
    adapter.setClickListenerHeader(clickListenerHeader);
    adapter.setLongClickListenerHeader(longClickListenerHeader);
    adapter.setClickListenerFirstBody(clickListenerBody);
    adapter.setLongClickListenerFirstBody(longClickListenerBody);
    adapter.setClickListenerBody(clickListenerBody);
    adapter.setLongClickListenerBody(longClickListenerBody);
    adapter.setClickListenerSection(clickListenerBody);
    adapter.setLongClickListenerSection(longClickListenerBody);
```

Hope it helps you.